# Check user like facebook page without permission request

Tags: javascript, facebook

Is there any way to check a user has like a facebook page without permission request?
The feature is similar like addmefast.com, when user click on Like button, I need to check whether a user has like a page or not.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't that kind of defeat the point of the request page, and probably volatile peoples privacy ? Something Facebook tries very hard not to appear to do...

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to check a user has like a facebook page without permission request?

Only if your app is running as a page tab app on that Facebook page.

If so, the info is contained inside the `signed_request` parameter.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Could you please provide an example how to check user's likes using signed_request?

Comment: If not mistaken, using signed_request only can check the particular facebook page. What I need to do is check user's like from different facebook page. For example, When user click on Fan page 1, then return a result(like the page or not). If user click on Fan page 2, then return another set of result.

Comment: Then you’ll have to get the user’s permission to read their likes first. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#likes